# Proof Verification: Continuity and Open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

Show that if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  is continuous, then the set $A =\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)<\alpha\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$

My attempt:

$f(x)< \alpha$ implies that if we have the open set $(-\infty, \alpha)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then by the global continuity theorem, we have that there exists an open set $H$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $H \cap \mathbb{R}= f^{-1}(G).$

This implies that $H= f^{-1}(G)$ which by definition is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x)<\alpha\}$ and is open.

Can anyone please verify this and check if my reasoning is ok?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, but:

1. Since $H\subset\mathbb R$, why do you write aboute $H\cap\mathbb R$? Why not just $H$?
2. Are you sure that you can use the “global continuity theorem”? It seems more likely that you are suppposed to prove it in this particular case.

Comment: For 1, I was just following the definition so did that, when in fact, just $H$ would have worked. For 2, I don't think  that we are required to prove that. That has already been proved in the text and I'm assuming I just have to use it and derive the result. We have only done the basics of topology, nothing too much. Thank you for your input!